# iphone 6 and android device media query conflict

Tags: responsive-design

6I am trying to target android device and iphone 6 with media queries.
My android device is ZTE Blade Vec 4G. I think it has same resolution with galaxy s3. (1280x720)

However my android device use iPhone 6 media queries even I specified them separately

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (min-device-width : 640px) and 
(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 375px) and (max-device-width : 667px) and
(orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue with iPhone6 and Motorola Moto G. Really need to address them separately. Nobody?